# grails - Render doesn't work in production mode

Tags: spring, grails

My render works well in development when I deploy the application I have an exception:

**HTTP Status 404 - /myApplication/WEB-INF/grails-app/views/myController/MyView.jsp**

```
def myView(){

    ....            
    render(view: "MyView", model: [params:params])
    return  

}
```

I found a fixed issue in JIRA but I don't know if there is exactly the same issue:

http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-5201?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel

My environment:
GGTS: 3.3.0.RELEASE

Grails:2.0.3

apache-tomcat-6.0.37

Comment: is it a url path you're using to access your app? `/myApplication/WEB-INF/grails-app/views/myController/MyView.jsp`? where you get it? also, noticed that at one place it's `MyView`, at another just `myView`

Comment: actually in my real code I wrote "MyView" but it is not correct it must be "myView". I didn't noticed this error because in development mode its works even if the gsp name was not correct. Thanks

Comment: If your controller method name is the same as your view name, you do not have to specify "view: 'myView'". By convention grails will render the view.

Comment: @Jils, so, it was incorrect view name? or you still have this issue

Comment: @Igor, Yes it was incorrect view name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we figured out, it was because of inconsistent view name.

It's very likely that you're using a Windows for development, and a Linux for production. Windows is usually case-insensitive for filenames, but Linux is case sensitive (usually). So on production system `myView.gsp` and `MyView.gsp` is two different files, you must use same case for filename and in your code.